# Whose past participle should I use here?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, past-perfect

I'm writing about a project I worked on in my PS. The project started in August and I joined in October. So which verb should I use here?

> The project had _______ for 2 months before I joined the team.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*For* calls for a timespan rather than a timepoint, so a perfect progressive construction works better than a simple perfect; and *start* would be very odd, since it ordinarily designates a single event, not a process<sup>†</sup>:

> The project *had been running* for two months before I joined the team.

Without the *for* you can use *start* and indicate a timepoint two months earlier:

> The project **had started** two months before I joined the team

---

<sup>†</sup> There are contexts in which *start* can take a progressive—*The project was just starting when I joined*—but a 'start' lasting two months suggests the project was floundering badly before you arrived!